# How to limit the CPU-cores used by scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, scipy, cpu-cores

I've got a program that uses scipy.integrate.quad(). When I use it I noticed that it uses all the cores on my PC, which I don't want as I want to run this script in parallel on multiple cores. Is there any way to restrict the function?

I have already tried limiting it with this command before import scipy and numpy:

```py
import os
import sys

os.environ.update(
    OMP_NUM_THREADS='1',
    OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS='1',
    NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS='1',
    MKL_NUM_THREADS='1',
)
```

Unfortunately that didn't help either. Are there other things I could try? My scipy uses openblas in case that is relevant too.

Answer (score 1):

What cores are used when by your computer is handled by the lower layers of your os. There is no way to modify the ammount of cores used for one process. If you want to run the programm multiple times in parallel, you should use multithreading and let the computer handle the workload by himself

Comment: The problem is that scipy integrates multithreading somewhere and I want to turn that off. When I replace the integrate.quad with my own integral function only one core is used as intended (Though of course that is incredibly slow as it was written in python). I know that setting the number of threads to one as in my code example above works for many numpy functions but doesn't seem to work for integrate.quad.

Comment: Why would you want to only use one core anyways?

Comment: I want to run multiple of them in parallel. Currently running them in parallel is slower than simply running them one after the other, hence only wanting to use one core per job.

Comment: I honestly still dont understand how you determine the ammount of cores used by a process. What os are you on?

Comment: On linux fedora. But python generally only allows one core to be used per process the only reason scipy can circumvent this is because the code isn't python code but Fortran (I believe)

Comment: I looked it up, C, C++, and Fortran. If there is no way to manipulate the behavior of the code through python (and i don't know any) and the native python algorithm is too slow then you might have to implement your own version in a faster language that meets your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Quad by itself should not use parallelism. What is your function you're integrating? (If it has linear algebra, it might be openblas that uses all cores by default etc)

Comment: I thought that was the case at first as well, but not only am I setting the threads for openblas to 1 already, the program reverts back to only using 1 core when I replace quad with my own python integral function. Are you sure quad doesn't use parallelism somewhere under the hood?

Comment: A minimal repro example would be helpful, along with your OS, python, numpy and scipy versions then.